# jQuery when show div (on slide) body background image fade effect change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**Slider (jquery.bxslider)** "[Sample Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/51bar.jpg)"

what i'm trying to achieved is when it slide a div, "the body" background image changes in fade transition, useful for theming a category, i'm new at jquery but i underestand a bit of it, so any help is appreciated

here's my code so far

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Welcome Page Ver.2</title>
    <!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
    <script src="scripts/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/plugins/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
    <script src="scripts/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/nav.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/tinybox.js"></script>
    <!-- bxSlider CSS file -->
    <link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="my.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider1">
        <div class="slide">1</div>
        <div class="slide">2</div>
        <div class="slide">3</div>
        <div class="slide">3</div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.slider1').bxSlider({
                slideWidth: 5000,
                minSlides: 1,
                maxSlides: 1,
                slideMargin: 10,
                infiniteLoop: true,
                hideControlOnEnd: false,
                mode: 'horizontal',
                useCSS: false,
                easing: 'easeOutElastic',
                speed: 2000
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

i added some sample pic

Comment: What are you asking for?

Answer (score 0):

Set the `mode:` to `'fade'` See [bxSlider documentation](http://bxslider.com/options) for more options.